# Text animation (shape ramp)

Tags: animation, text-object

Can blender using a text shape ramp effect as in the after effects ? how if using a blender ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a curve modifier applied to your text object though it will distort the text shape along the curve slightly. Not sure if that is the effect you are going for or not

[image]